# Top-down merge sorting. Merge method abstract exchange method

Tags: c, sorting, merge, mergesort

What is the problem? Why is there always a fixed value of comparisons and swaps? And am I correct in counting swaps and comparisons in principle? I mean, do I accidentally count them in the wrong places? Maybe in some places it is not necessary to do this? Please help me because I really can't figure out what's wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void mergeAbstract(int *a, int lb, int split, int ub, int *count, int *swaps)
{
    int size = ub - lb + 1;
    int *sub = (int *)malloc((ub + 1) * sizeof(int)); 
    int i = 0, j = size - 1, k = lb;
    int s;
    for (s = 0; s < split + 1 - lb; s++) sub[s] = a[lb + s];
    for (s = split + 1 - lb; s < size; s++) sub[s] = a[ub - (s - (split + 1 -lb))];

    while (i <= j) {
        (*count) += 2;
        if (sub[i] > sub[j]) {
            (*swaps)++;
            a[k] = sub[j];
            j--;
        } else {
            (*swaps)++;
            a[k] = sub[i];
            i++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    (*count)++;
    free(sub);
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub, int *count, int *swaps) {
    long split;

    if (lb < ub) {
        split = (lb + ub) / 2;

        mergeSort(a, lb, split, count, swaps);
        mergeSort(a, split + 1, ub, count, swaps);
        mergeAbstract(a, lb, split, ub, count, swaps);
    }
}

void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 10;
    int *arr = NULL; 
    arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof *arr); 
    int c = 0; 
    int *count = &c; 
    int h = 0; 
    int *swaps = &h; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for (s = 0; s < n; s++)
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;

    arrprint(arr, n);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1, count, swaps);
    arrprint(arr, n);

    free(arr);
    puts("");

    printf("Comparison ans swaps : %d %d\n", *count ,*swaps);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't know, that's why I'm here with my questions.But for some reason, the value is always the same.I don't think it should be like this.And do I count these values correctly at all?

Comment: Calling the variable `swaps` may be a misnomer. You increment for _both_ the `if` part _and_ the `else`, so, of course, it is derived from the total length of the original array, regardless of the amount of randomness in the array. That is, the number of comparisons/moves is related to `n * log2(n)` in a fixed manner. mergesort doesn't "swap" as one thinks about swapping in bubblesort. In other words, you _are_ getting the counts that one would expect.

Comment: `mergeAbstract` is incrementing `(*swaps)` exactly `size` (`ub - lb + 1`) times and does not depend on the values in the array at all. So the total number of swaps for the full recursion only depends on the length of the array. The total number of swaps will be approximately n*log_2(n).

Comment: @IanAbbott I will need to estimate the time complexity of the algorithm.And therefore..what should I count and where to get the n log n graph (after making a table for 100, 200, etc. elements)?)

Comment: @CraigEstey I will need to estimate the time complexity of the algorithm.And therefore..what should I count and where to get the n log n graph (after making a table for 100, 200, etc. elements)?)

Comment: The time complexity _is_ `n*log2(n)`. The time is bounded [mostly] by the memory fetch/store. You can assume that the compare is [relatively] zero cost So, assume a fetch or store is T time units. Assume a compare takes T [worst case instead of zero]. The merge has fetch and store to `sub`, so 2T. merge is a fetch, compare, and store to move back from `sub`. Total time is `(5T * n*log2(n))`, which is [still] `O(n*log2(n))` because `O(constant * n*log2(n))` is just `O(n*log2(n))`

Comment: In big-O notation, the time complexity is `O(n*log(n))`. The base of the logarithm does not need to be specified in big-O notation because change of base is just a constant factor, and constant factors are ignored in big-O notation. In reality, the number of moves for a specific N is not _exactly_ proportional to `N*log(N)`, but it is close enough. (In fact, for merge sort, if N is an exact power of 2, then the number of moves will be exactly proportional to `N*log(N)`, but for other values of N it is not exact.)